# How to create DAGs with Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, airflow, dagster

I'm new to Spark and I've realized that, for the pipeline I'm making, it would be much more convenient to have a DAG to represent the pipeline to improve monitoring, scheduling, etc.

I connected Spark to my MySQL database and ran a few scripts with Spark dataframes using PyTorch and it worked great. I was able to apply machine learning models and stuff.

The problems started once I started looking to set up a DAG. I had read Dagster is more lightweight then airflow, so I decided to use Dagster, but this created issues.

My goal was, for each set of transformations to do to my Spark data frame, I was going to define separate @op functions in dagster that would let me put them into a nice flow chart so I could observe them during execution from the dagit GUI.

However, this doesn't work because apparently you can't pass Spark DFs between these functions since dagster serializes the outputs and then deserializes them once inputted into the next function.

Airflow also has a similar problem it seems whereby, in order to pass data between wo tasks, you have to use the XCom (Cross Communication) to facilitate communication and data exchange between tasks within a DAG.

Thus, it seems like neither of these are suitable for passing data between different tasks, so I'm confused, how does one use DAGs to organize data processing in Spark?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed many workflow tools can handle executing DAG's, but they are not optimized for integrating Spark, passing DataFrames around and validating schemas as early as possible. We created a Framework doing exactly that, see [www.smartdatalake.io](http://www.smartdatalake.io) and try out our getting started: https://smartdatalake.io/docs/getting-started/setup.
The limiting point for you might be that it is still more focused and Spark/Scala, and PySpark is not yet fully supported, e.g. only 1:1 DataFrame transformation for now.